# How to slowly store higher voltage from low power source?

Tags: voltage-regulator, low-power, solar-energy, buck-boost, energy-harvesting

I want to use a small solar panel (about 1V 15mA in ambient light) and then boost its voltage to 6V to slowly charge a 6V battery or capacitor. I have experimented with some generic boost converters, but they usually required more current than what the very small solar panel could provide, so what is the best way to slowly boost a very low power source to store power at a higher voltage?

Comment: 15mW might be less than your battery leakage but they are called Energy harvest IC's or Joule Thief ccts

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Ooo I;ll research those, thanks!

Comment: @NO_GUI Not that I'm recommending Maxim, but [this harvester IC](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX20361.pdf) is the kind of thing Tony was alluding to. (Output voltage not right, though, and needs an MCU I fear.)

Comment: First, do the obvious thing: check whether they make a different solar panel with 6V 2.5mA :)